# Docker compose build failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker compose build: no configuration file provided: not found

I were trying to use "docker compose build", but it failed with "no configuration file provided: not found".

I think this can be solved...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read "How do I ask a good question?" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . No one will help you if you dont show the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

usually, the docker-compose.yml file is located at the /etc folder. can you confirm if you are executing from the file location?

To find the docker-compose.yml file if the location is unknown, you can use the find command to do it

you need to execute this **as a root user** or else you will see many permission-denied errors.

> find / -type f -name docker-compose.yml

once you find the location of docker-compose.yml, change the directory into the folder.
then execute respective docker-compose commands. Also please verify the file extension should be yml or yaml.

please try these and let us know in case of any issues

Comment: Hi, why do you think that there is a standard location for `docker-compose` files? Can  you provide some supporting link?

Comment: Hi @pierpy I didn't say there is a standard location for the docker-compose file. we can put where ever we want and use the -f flag for using the docker-compose command. I have added the **find command** for a user to find the location if there is an issue identifying the path of docker-compose.yml.

usually, configuration files are set in the /etc by industry standard.

Comment: I think you are confusing docker main settings with the meaning of a docker-compose yaml file...